# Module won't work in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x

This has been troubling me for the past hour. My python script won't run; however, if I select 'check module', input the code, and run the same thing it works. It's a very simple script:

```
import pyscreenshot as getImage

im = getImage.grab(bbox=(1300,800,1500,850))
im.save("screen.png")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run"? Perhaps it is running but saving the image in a folder that you don't expect.

Comment: @JohnColeman The script doesn't fully run. It pauses/freezes when it gets to "im = getImage.grab(bbox=(1300,800,1500,850))". The script is still running, but nothing happens.

Comment: What OS are you using @user3133476?

Comment: @Mr.Zeus Windows 8.1

Comment: Have you installed PIL or Pillow @user3133476? (it says to install it in the tutorial, the on on PyPI)

Comment: Yeah i have Pillow/PIL installed. @Mr.Zeus

Comment: You may want to install another one of the other back-ends @user3133476.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `childprocess=False` as IDLE has problems with multiprocessing. IDLE runs user code in a separate process so with pyscreenshot IDLE hangs and seems like the module won't work. You may go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293178/can-multiprocessing-process-class-be-run-from-idle/35297841#35297841) to know more.

An option is to turn off multiprocessing by setting `childprocess=False`.

Try:

```
import pyscreenshot as getImage 
im = getImage.grab(bbox=(1300,800,1500,850), childprocess=False) 
im.save("screen.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running through terminal and it will work.

Although I do not know why this happens exactly (probably ask those who maintain it) I can tell you it is because of some terminal dependant function that is created while running.

The IDLE is not actually a terminal so it cannot run exactly like a terminal (although it outputs the same content, it is not a terminal).  For example running `os.get_terminal_size()` under the IDLE will not work yet the terminal will.  There are also some functions in PIL that perform in the same way.

Anyway [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359379/pyscreenshot-is-hanging-python-3-4) shows a pretty similar code and it is mentioned it doesn't work under the IDLE.